# Site getting stuck on Safari while cropping image with cropper js

Tags: jquery, safari, cropperjs

I'm stuck on an issue with Safari. I'm using cropper js with jQuery to crop and upload images. My site works perfectly on other browsers except for Safari.

When I upload an image and hit the crop button my site most of the time gets stuck and becomes unresponsive. There are no errors or warnings in the console.

One thing I have noticed is issue occurs mostly with large-sized images. Upon click, I do some adjustments to the uploaded image and then run the following cropper js function.

```
  cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toBlob((blob)=>{
  let fileInputElement = $('#uploaded_image')[0];
  let file = new File([blob], imageToProcess.name,{type:imageToProcess.type, lastModified:new Date().getTime()});
  let container = new DataTransfer();
  container.items.add(file);
  fileInputElement.files = container.files;
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, but with photos that are not from the origin of the device regardless of the size, I share my code in case it helps you in any way.

```
canvas = cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                    width: canvasWidth,
                    height: canvasHeight,
});
canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
     var formData = new FormData();
     formData.append("imageFromCanvasCrop", blob);

}, 'image/jpeg',1);
```

Comment: Hi, I was doing a lot of tests, and the conclusion is that when I download an image on an iPhone from the iPhone browser it gives a special treatment changing something in its composition.

the only solution that seems viable is to crop the image in the backend when it is from iPhone until they solve this BUG.

Answer (score 0):

**The explanation of my case:** when trying to upload a file, cropper.getCroppedCanvas() function get me a warning "**canvas area exceeds the maximum limit (width * height > 16777216).**", this caused the images not to be sent and when I managed to save them on my server, it generated a transparent image.

**Why is this happening?:**
getCroppedCanvas() have one option, if you do not
specify the **maxWidth and maxHeight**, Cropper **defaults to Infinite**, this may cause the browser to run out of memory.

**The solutions:**

I use the **cropper.getImageData();** function to obtain the actual image attributes, specifically use **naturalHeight** and **naturalWidth** and use these values to define **maxWidth** and **maxHeight** on getCroppedCanvas() function:

```
const imageData = cropper.getImageData();

cropper.getCroppedCanvas({
                    width: canvasWidth,
                    height: canvasHeight,
                    maxWidth:imageData.naturalHeight,
                    maxHeight:imageData.naturalWidth,
                    imageSmoothingQuality: 'high',
                });
```

I hope this can be of service to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Incase stuck and not able to crop image

```js
const pixelRatio: window.devicePixelRatio
```

change value from  `window.devicePixelRatio` to `0.5`